# java declare anonymous class using proxy api

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, minecraft

This morning I fell into a particular case that never happened to me before. I'm developing a Minecraft plugin using the minecraft server API which is usually called NMS with reference to the name of its packages (eg net.minecraft.server.v1_13_R1 for version 1.13).

The main problem with the use of the minecraft server API is that it is difficult to write a cross version code: indeed the name of the packages changes with each new version.

When the plugin only supports two versions it is usually easier to use the interfaces to write two different codes depending on the version. But when you have to support a dozen different versions (and this is my case), it's a bad idea (the plugin would be much too heavy, it would have to import every jar in the IDE, and I would have to redo the code with each new version). 
In these cases I usually use reflection but I do not think it's possible here:

```
            packet = packetConstructor.newInstance(
                    new MinecraftKey("q", "q") {
                        @Override
                        public String toString() {
                            return "FML|HS";
                        }
                    },
                    packetDataSerializerConstructor.newInstance(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(data)));
```

As you probably guessed MinecraftKey is a class from NMS and I was told to use Java Dynamic Proxy API. I have never used it and would like to know if you would know a place that would explain to me how to do it simply? If you know of another better method that interests me too!

When I think about it, I think that this is really a lot of trouble for a tiny piece of code x)

EDIT :
My plugin uses the PacketPlayOutCustomPayload (aka plugin messages) to communicate with the mods of the players. It allows me to send a message (a byte []) on a particular channel (a String). But with the 1.13 this String has been replaced by a MinecraftKey (a wrapper for the String that replaces some characters and requires the use of a ":"). This poses a problem when players connect to 1.12 on my 1.13 server so I do not have a choice: I have to override the MinecraftKey object in this case.

Comment: If you're doing plugins, wouldn't it be easier to use Bukkit or Spigot APIs?

Comment: This is true but unfortunately, it does not allow me to do what I want (as you can see I override the toString method MinecraftKey because else I cannot send the right String).

Comment: Does [this thread in spigot forums](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/what-is-a-minecraftkey.248413/) help you in any way?

Comment: I'd run away from NMS if possible

Comment: No, it does not really help me. But I owe you an explanation: My plugin uses the PacketPlayOutCustomPayload (aka plugin messages) to communicate with the mods of the players. It allows me to send a message (a byte []) on a particular channel (a String). But with the 1.13 this String has been replaced by a MinecraftKey (a wrapper for the String that replaces some characters and requires the use of a ":"). This poses a problem when players connect to 1.12 on my 1.13 server so I do not have a choice: I have to override the MinecraftKey object in this case.

Comment: Interesting. I recommend adding this detail to the question :P

Comment: It's okay, added ;)

Comment: You should use gradle/maven and modules for such project, each mc version have separate module with own implementations of that common interfaces to support NMS code. Then you can make build process that will make one fat jar for every version or create separate .jar per version, you can also use some tools that will allow you to generate that classes for each version when building a project from single template file.

Comment: Which “Java Dynamic Proxy API” had, whoever told you to use it, in mind? The built-in proxy generator only supports interfaces and `MinecraftKey` in your code example clearly isn’t an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t really think using proxy classes is good solution here, it will only make it harder to debug, but if you need something like that you should use library like ByteBuddy: (as java can’t generate proxy for a class, only interfaces are allowed)

```
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.FixedValue;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeKey someKey = new SomeKey("my", "key");
        System.out.println(someKey); // :<
        // this class should be cached/saved somewhere, do not create new one each time.
        Class<? extends SomeKey> loaded = new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(SomeKey.class)
                .method(named("toString").and(returns(String.class).and(takesArguments(0))))
                .intercept(FixedValue.value("something"))
                .make()
                .load(Main.class.getClassLoader()).getLoaded();
        someKey = loaded.getConstructor(String.class, String.class).newInstance("what", "ever");
        System.out.println(someKey); // YeY
    }
}
class SomeKey {
    final String group;
    final String name;
    public SomeKey(String group, String name) {
        this.group = group;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGroup() { return this.group; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return group+":"+name;
    }
}
```

But I would just create separate modules in my project, one that does only work with real bukkit API and contains many interfaces to represent NMS types in some normalised and readable way.
And separate modules for each version, then you will not have much code to duplicate, as most of it will be abstracted and handled by that “core/base” module.
Then you can build it as one single fat jar or separate .jar per version.

Other solution might be using some template engines and preprocessors to generate java sources on build time, see how fastutil is doing this:
https://github.com/vigna/fastutil

And yet another solution for simple classes and parts of code would be to use build-in javascript or external script language like groovy to also create this pattern-line but in runtime. But I would use this only for simplest stuff.

Also for just using methods you can just use normal reflections.

You can also always inject into netty and instead of using default packet serializer just write own bytes, then you don't need that key at all.

Comment: Thank you very much it works! ByteBuddy is a bit heavy so I'm going to see if I can not use asm directly.

Comment: Stop worrying that much about size of .jar... there is no reason to care about it that much. But there is also "Javassist" library, it will allow you to just write that java-like code or you can even extend that class using javascript engine build-in into jre.